# Child category is set current-cat on parent page

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child, categories

I have parent categories which have childs. I'm listing child categories on parent category page.

**I'm using archive.php template.**

Now I'm facing issue with `current-cat` class on parent category page.
Seems that my first child category is getting `current-cat` class when on parent category page. This `current-cat` class should be on only when on current category page.

For example my parent category is **Fruits**. And when I'm on **Fruits** (category/fruits) page I can see child categories **Apple**, **Orange**, **Banana**. Problem is that **Apple** is getting `current-cat` class on **Fruits** page.

It should get that class only when on **Apple** page (category/fruits/apple).

Here is my current code:

```
global $wp_query;

$ID = $wp_query->posts[0]->ID; 
$postcat = get_the_category($ID);
$cat = $postcat[0]->cat_ID; 
$thiscat = get_category ($cat); 
$parent = $thiscat->category_parent; 

if ($parent == 0) {

}

else { 

    $subcategories = get_categories('child_of='.$parent);
    $items='';
        foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
            if($thiscat->term_id == $subcat->term_id) 
              $current = ' current-cat'; 
            else $current = ''; 
              $items .= '
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$subcat->term_id.$current.'"> 
                <a href="'.get_category_link( $subcat->term_id ).'" title="'.$subcat->description.'">'.$subcat->name.' </a>
            </li>';
    }
    echo "<ul>$items</ul>";
    }

?>
```

How to fix my code?

Comment: Using curly braces with  your `if` statements, and proper indenting of your code, will help you troubleshoot much easier.

Comment: Is this code on an `archive` template? The problem is the way you are checking `thiscat` - you're loading an actual *post*, which is almost certainly *in the "Apple" cat* (and apparently also in the *Fruit* cat).  If this is on an archive template, you can get the category by using `queried_object` instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm using archive.php template. I changed `$thiscat = get_queried_object($cat); ` But now I'm not seeing child categories at all. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are on the **archive** template, this code:

```
global $wp_query;

$ID = $wp_query->posts[0]->ID; 
$postcat = get_the_category($ID);
$cat = $postcat[0]->cat_ID; 
$thiscat = get_category ($cat);
```

Is loading the category *from the first post*.  That first post could be in one, two, or multiple categories, so getting the category ID this way is not reliable.

Instead, there are some other ways - try this method - to get the category ID for which the archive is intended to be loading:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$thiscat = get_category($cat);
$parent = ($thiscat->category_parent) ? $thiscat->category_parent : $thiscat->term_id;
```

Comment: Okey, I see the problem. I tried with your code but still not seeing any child cats on parent page.

Comment: Hi Ace - I've made a change.  I thought you could take it from where I got you, but I've now shown you how to get the `$parent` properly set as well (basically, it says "If there is a parent catetgory, use that, otherwise use this category id)